# Riemann function is cliquish

Tags: general-topology, functions, continuity

Let $(X,\tau$) be a topological space, $(Y,d)$ a metric space, $f:X \rightarrow Y$ a function. We say $f$ is *cliquish* at $x \in X$, if $\forall \varepsilon >0$ $\forall U$ open neighbourhood of $x$, there exists a non-empty open $V, V \subset U$ such that $\forall x_1, x_2 \in V: d(f(x_1), f(x_2)) < \varepsilon$.

I wan to prove that the [Riemann function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_function) is cliquish (as found [here](https://dml.cz/bitstream/handle/10338.dmlcz/125901/MathBohem_117-1992-2_11.pdf), Example 1.2). I do not know how to show that
$$
\left\vert \frac{1}{q_1} - \frac{1}{q_2}  \right\vert < \varepsilon
$$
for $x_1 = p_1/q_1, x_2 = p_2/q_2$.

Comment: Isn't cliquish just uniform continuity ? Not quite but somehow related.

Comment: @KurtG. I read it and I am guessing it means _continuity._ I am guessing under general conditions on $X$ the condition "for all neighbourhood $U$ of $x,$ there exists a open-set $x \in V \subset U$ such that..." can be reduced to "there exists an open set $x \in V$ such that..."

Comment: Looks like. If $f$ is continuous at $x$ then $\forall\varepsilon>0$ $\exists W$ open such that $d(f(x),f(y))<\varepsilon$ $\forall y\in W$. If $U$ is an open neighbourhood of $x$ take $V=U\cap W$ and then for all $x_1,x_2\in V$ we have $d(f(x_1),f(x_2))\le d(f(x_1),f(y))+d(f(y),f(x_2))<2\varepsilon$. Looks cliquish, doesn't it ?